# Why does this function overloaded for three integer types fail to compile?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, overloading

This attempt to define a function overloaded for three sizes of integers fails. Why?

```
byte hack(byte x)
{
   return x+1;
}

unsigned short hack(unsigned short x)
{
   return x+2;
}

unsigned int hack(unsigned int x)
{
   return x+3;
}
```

The compiler tells me:
    zzz.cpp:98: error: redefinition of ‘unsigned int hack(unsigned int)’
    zzz.cpp:88: error: ‘byte hack(byte)’ previously defined here

Comment: Since `byte` isn't a standard type, perhaps you can look up its definition and provide it here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your compiler/code thinks that *byte* and *unsigned int* are the same thing...

Comment: +1 because yes, that's what my compiler (gcc) thinks.  Why?  Because someone at my desk stupidly wrote "typedef unsigned int byte;" as I just discovered a minute ago chasing another bug.

Comment: @DarenW: Probably should just use `std::uin8_t` directly. Or `char` if you don't mean octet.

Answer (score 0):

Overloaded functions can differ only by their parameters count and/or types and not the return type. So, these are three different functions.

Comment: Last i checked, functions could differ by return type if their arguments' types differed as well.  That's kinda how template functions work.  :P  The three are different functions anyway; the fact that they have the same name means nothing to the compiler, since C++ turns the names into something like hack_ii_i anyway.  The name's just a convenience for humans.